# Pasting external PDF vector graphics without losing ability to export them

Tags: pdf-format, mac-os-x, palettes, python, clipboard

**Update: Problem persists in version 10.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.5**

As in previous versions, *Mathematica* 9 on Mac OS X (10.7.5 here) still has a problem with pasted `PDF` graphics that were copied from external applications such as `Preview.app` or `Skim.app` (I usually use the latter).

To see the problem (**this is only supposed to work on Mac**), try the following:

```
Export["t.pdf", "Hello"];

SystemOpen["t.pdf"]
```

In the `PDF` viewer, activate the `select` tool, select all or part of the image and copy it to the clipboard (this is automatically copied in `PDF` format).

Now in *Mathematica*, type the line

```
Export["t1.pdf",  ];
```

and insert the copied `PDF` directly in the slot for the second argument by performing a `paste` from the clipboard.

Evaluate the cell and then look at the result:

```
First@Import["t1.pdf"]
```

[image: screen shot]

The result is empty. One can also observe that the pasted `PDF` in the above example looks like it's been rasterized and is being displayed at the wrong resolution. It actually isn't rasterized, but the display looks ugly and the export of such pasted `PDF` simply doesn't work. To fix this, I had written the following palette some time ago:

```
CreatePalette[Column[{Button["Convert PDF on clipboard",
     Module[{pdf, out = "/tmp/MathematicaOutput.pdf",
       prog = "from AppKit import *\nboard=NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()\nresult = board.dataForType_(NSPDFPboardType)\nif result:\n\tresult.writeToFile_atomically_('**FILENAME**',1)\n\" | /usr/bin/python"}, 
            Run["printf \"" <> 
        StringReplace[prog, {"**FILENAME**" -> out}]];
      CopyToClipboard[If[FileExistsQ[out], pdf = Import[out, "PDF"];
        (*DeleteFile[out]*);
        pdf[[1]], "No PDF"]];
      ], Appearance -> "Palette"],
    "Click before pasting externally generated PDF"}], 
  WindowTitle -> "Convert External PDF"];
```

After evaluating this, a palette is created that you have to click right after copying a `PDF` from an external application. If you then do the `paste` operation again in the following line:

```
Export["t2.pdf",   ];

First@Import["t2.pdf"]
```

> $\mathtt{Hell}$

The result is the expected `PDF`. There is another issue related to cropping of the `PDF`. The above results are obtained using `Skim`, but when using `Preview` the crop box is lost and the original bounding box is used.

My question is: **Is there a simpler way to get pasted `PDF` from external applications on Mac to display properly in the notebook and then export correctly?**

Comment: Regarding your question if it happens on other systems too: I just want to note that the ability to paste PDFs is an OS X only feature, and I *think* the PDFs won't show when the notebook is opened on other systems.

Comment: @Szabolcs Good point. However, if _Mathematica_ can import `PDF` on other systems, then my guess would be that pasted `PDF`s should also be visible there. But I've never checked to make sure...

Comment: @Szabolcs According to my notes from more than a year ago, I reported this as a bug. Do you agree that the bug tag can be added?

Comment: According to [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/142898?p_p_auth=t0cFZ8do) report pasted PDFs are visible only under OS X.

Answer (score 5):

This is a possible solution that I came up with after looking at another answer by @Ragfield: [Encoding format used by GraphicsData?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5592/245)

I had to modify the function `decodePICT` in that post to cut out the leading zero bytes:

```
DecodePDF[data_String] := 
  Module[{slash, backslash, zero, LF, CR, decode, codes, len, 
    i}, {slash, backslash, zero, LF, CR} = ToCharacterCode["/\\0\n\r"];
   decode[char_] := If[char == slash, backslash - zero, char - zero];
   len = Length[codes = ToCharacterCode[data]];
   i = 1;
   Last@Last@
     Reap@While[i <= len - 1, 
       Which[codes[[i]] == LF || codes[[i]] == CR, i++, 
        codes[[i]] == backslash, i += 4, True, 
        Sow@BitAnd[
          BitOr[BitShiftLeft[decode[codes[[i]]], 2], 
           BitShiftRight[decode[codes[[i + 1]]], 4]], 255];
        i++;
        If[i <= len - 1, 
         Sow@BitAnd[
           BitOr[BitShiftLeft[decode[codes[[i]]], 4], 
            BitShiftRight[decode[codes[[i + 1]]], 2]], 255]];
        i++;
        If[i <= len - 1, 
         Sow@BitAnd[
           BitOr[BitShiftLeft[decode[codes[[i]]], 6], 
            BitShiftRight[decode[codes[[i + 1]]], 0]], 255]];
        i += 2;]]];

convertPDF[badPDF_RawBoxes] := Module[
  {
   str = First@
     Cases[InputForm[badPDF], GraphicsData["PDF", dat_] :> dat, 
      Infinity],
   out = "/tmp/MathematicaOutput.pdf"
   },
  Export[out, DecodePDF[str], "Binary"];
  First@Import[out]
  ]
```

Now if you type

```
convertPDF[   ]
```

and paste the externally generated `PDF` into the space above, then the result will be the "fixed" `PDF` which satisfies *both* requirements: it looks smooth and it can be exported as usual, with no apparent problem.

The next step is to put this into a `Palette` again. I'll do that after testing this approach some more (unless someone comes up with a better idea).

**Edit**

**The above was exposition to explain what I did; you don't need to copy that code**

Here is the final result: a `Palette` that implements the above conversion for a `PDF` on the clipboard. It's a drop-in replacement for the `Palette` I posted in the question, but it doesn't require python and it doesn't run any external commands. It's also faster than the python-based conversion:

```
CreatePalette[Column[{Button["Convert PDF on clipboard",
     Module[
      {
       str,
       out = "/tmp/MathematicaOutput.pdf",
       decodePDF
       },
      decodePDF[data_String] := 
       Module[{slash, backslash, zero, LF, CR, decode, codes, len, 
         i}, {slash, backslash, zero, LF, CR} = 
         ToCharacterCode["/\\0\n\r"];
        decode[char_] := 
         If[char == slash, backslash - zero, char - zero];
        len = Length[codes = ToCharacterCode[data]];
        i = 1;
        Last@
         Last@Reap@
           While[i <= len - 1, 
            Which[codes[[i]] == LF || codes[[i]] == CR, i++, 
             codes[[i]] == backslash, i += 4, True, 
             Sow@BitAnd[
               BitOr[BitShiftLeft[decode[codes[[i]]], 2], 
                BitShiftRight[decode[codes[[i + 1]]], 4]], 255];
             i++;

             If[i <= len - 1, 
              Sow@BitAnd[
                BitOr[BitShiftLeft[decode[codes[[i]]], 4], 
                 BitShiftRight[decode[codes[[i + 1]]], 2]], 255]];
             i++;

             If[i <= len - 1, 
              Sow@BitAnd[
                BitOr[BitShiftLeft[decode[codes[[i]]], 6], 
                 BitShiftRight[decode[codes[[i + 1]]], 0]], 255]];
             i += 2;]]];
      str = First@Append[
         Cases[NotebookGet[
                     ClipboardNotebook[]], 
          GraphicsData["PDF", dat_] :> dat, Infinity], ""]
      ;
      CopyToClipboard[
       If[str =!= "",
        Export[out, decodePDF[str], "Binary"];
        First@Import[out],
        "No PDF"
        ]
       ];
      ], Appearance -> "Palette"],
    "Click before pasting externally generated PDF"}], 
  WindowTitle -> "Convert External PDF"];
```

There are some things that don't work correctly with this `PDF` conversion, but that was the same in my original approach: when copying from multipage `PDF` documents, some color and background information can be lost. However, the main reason why `PDF` copy and paste on the Mac is nice (as opposed to bitmaps which are always a viable alternative) is that it produces resolution independent outlines for fonts, lines and shapes - and those properties are definitely preserved with this `Palette`.

**Edit 2**

The remaining problems mentioned above imply that this solution doesn't produce a better outcome than my original one, but this answer does run faster because it doesn't have to initialize python and the `AppKit` module every time.

To fix the problems that remain, I have always been using an additional intermediate step that uses `ghostscript`. The Mac Application for this is called `FontBegone` and can be downloaded [from my web site](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/FontBegone/). It requires `ghostscript`, which can be obtained conveniently as part of a $\TeX$ installation.

With this, my personal workflow for copying `PDF` is: highlight the desired crop area in `Skim` and copy. Tap the `FontBegone` icon, then tap the button for the `Palette` in this answer. Now paste into *Mathematica*, and you're done.

Having this ability to paste `PDF` into a notebook completes the circle in a workflow that is quite unique to Mac OS X. The other half of the circle is the ability to copy as `PDF` from *Mathematica* into other applications such as `LyX` to create $\LaTeX$ documents with vector graphics produced in *Mathematica* (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5144/245)). We can move `PDF` graphics around freely in both directions via the clipboard.

More discussion (currently based on my original solution) can be found [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/pasteExternalPDF.html).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly what you want, but if you File > Print > Save as PDF then the content will appear correctly. It's only Export where it doesn't appear.

Comment: +1 because it could lead to an automated solution too.

Comment: I just figured out a solution based on one of your earlier posts! Thanks for [that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5552/245)...