# MathLink Graphical Output (Plots) to File

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, mathlink-or-wstp, linux

In a custom Mathematica frontend based on MathLink I try to make use of plots produced in Notebooks. The idea is to write them to files whenever they get produced.

According to C-code snippets I found online the following should store all plots in postscript cells in a Mathematica file "picture_book" if `$Display = "stdout"` is executed in the beginning:

```
case DISPLAYPKT:
  if(MLGetString(link, &output_string)){
    if(first_PS_piece){
      first_PS_piece = FALSE;
      if(picture_book){
        fprintf(picture_book, "%s", ps_cellheader);
      }
    }
    if(picture_book){
      fprintf(picture_book, "%s", output_string);
    }
    MLDisownString(link, output_string);
  }
  break;

case DISPLAYENDPKT:
  if(MLGetString(link, &output_string)){
    if(picture_book){
      fprintf(picture_book, "%s", output_string);
    }
    MLDisownString(link, output_string);
  }
  first_PS_piece = TRUE;
  break;
```

However, when I run `$Display = "stdout"` at first, I get the error message

```
Graphics::opset: Option DefaultAxesStyle is not set in Options[Graphics].
```

twice, each time I try `Plot`. Trying to set `DefaultAxesStyle` did not work.

The code above appears in the loop which handles the output after running Mathematica commands with MathLink. I verified that it retrieves other output packets (not shown), but `DISPLAYPKT` packages are never received.

This code might be outdated and so I wonder if I need to do anything else in order to obtain proper output packets. Note that I am on Linux.

A different (disfavored) approach would be to use the `Export["plot.eps",plot]` function in order to export each plot to a separate file. How would I achieve this with minimal impact on existing Notebooks? I.e. can I redefine the `Plot` command such that each is automatically exported to a separate file with automatic naming?

**Edit**

After some changes my frontend receives textual Output of the following kind when I call `Plot` or similar (abreviated example output)

```
Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Line}}}, {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {None, None},  AxesOrigin -> {1., 0.05}, Method -> {},  PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {0.04978707039998921, 0.3678794261559552}},  PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding ->   {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

If I execute these outputs manually inside a Notebook in the default frontend it seems to produce the plots. Is it a consistent approach to detect this `Graphics[]` output and to write it to a file (which kind of file) and then execute that file manually (or later automatically) in the Mathematica interface to produce visual plots? Or could this output be missing some information or be more general for different plot commands?

**Edit 2**

Motivated by the answers and comments below and the Mathematica documentation I tried the command:

```
Off[FrontEndObject::notavail]; Get["Version5`Graphics`"]; Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

Together with custom `Format` definitions for `Graphics` (and similar) this would re-enable the 'old fashioned' way of retrieving display output described above. However I do not completely understand how to deal with the abbreviate postscript output (shown below in shortened form). Obviously postscript is missing some definitions to render it. How do I convert this to a complete consistent postscript file?

```
%!
%%Creator: Mathematica
%%AspectRatio: .61803 
MathPictureStart
/Mabs {
Mgmatrix idtransform
Mtmatrix dtransform
} bind def
/Mabsadd { Mabs
3 -1 roll add
3 1 roll add
exch } bind def
%% Graphics
%%IncludeResource: font Courier
%%IncludeFont: Courier
/Courier findfont 10  scalefont  setfont
% Scaling calculations
0 0.31831 0 0.618034 [
[.15915 -0.0125 -9 -9 ]
Mfstroke
% End of Graphics
MathPictureEnd
:[font = postscript; PostScript; formatAsPostScript; output; inactive; pictureLeft = 100; pictureWidth = 300; pictureHeight = 300;]
```

It is probably not feasible without the official front end, is it?

**Edit 3**

Following advice given below in comments I tried the following definitions to print all plots to files. Is this consistent or is there a better way to do it? (First I had tried to redefine `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` directly, because it seems more elegant to me. However this resulted  in recursions or it would have no effect whatsoever.)

```
useMyGraphics[vars__] := 
 Block[{Graphics = myGraphics, Graphics3D = myGraphics3D}, vars]
Format[myGraphics[vars__]] := 
 Export["picture.png", Graphics[vars], ImageResolution -> 300]
Format[myGraphics3D[vars__]] := 
 Export["picture3D.png", Graphics3D[vars], ImageResolution -> 300]
Protect[myGraphics];
Protect[myGraphics3D];
Protect[useMyGraphics];
$Pre = useMyGraphics
```

Answer (score 2):

Since *Mathematica* version 6 you always need the native *Mathematica* FrontEnd for `Export`ing graphics because starting from this version all graphical `Export`-related functionality is moved into the FrontEnd.

But you probably still can use the old kernel-based graphical functionality from version 5 by evaluating:

```
<< Version5`Graphics`
```

Old graphical functions are also directly accessible via the `` Graphics`Legacy`* `` context:

```
Names["Graphics`Legacy`*"]
```

> ```
> {"ContourPlot", "DensityPlot", "Graphics", "ListContourPlot", \
> "ListDensityPlot", "ListPlot", "ListPlot3D", "ParametricPlot", \
> "ParametricPlot3D", "Plot", "Plot3D"}
> ```

These old-fashioned graphical functions by default generate *Mathematica* abbreviated PostScript (`"MPS"`) code without using the FrontEnd by

```
Display["stdout", #, "MPS"] &
```

You can generate EPS code via

```
DisplayString[#, "EPS"]&
```

but there may be some [difficulties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32886/280).

Comment: Ok, this helps a lot for clarification already. However I am not entirely sure if I should 'implement' this mechanism in my frontend as it seems to be outdated already. I suspect that the computation of the plot data itself still happens inside the Kernel, so it should report Objects of some kind to the interface. In fact after a few changes I receive now (I am not sure which change caused it) `Graphics[]` output in my fronted (see my edit to the question). Is it maybe a better (consistent) solution to use this to produce visual plots?

Comment: It is bad idea to rely on outdated and unsupported part of software which is subject for (possible) removing in future versions. Strictly speaking, `Graphics` expression is not always self-consistent and independent from the kernel, it can contain `Dynamic` elements, for example `Ticks->{f1,f2}` where `f1` and `f2` are functions defined in the kernel and dynamically called by the FrontEnd when rendering `Graphics` on screen. This is how ``CustomTicks`` package works.

Answer (score 2):

This is to answer:

> Can I redefine the `Plot` command such that each is automatically exported to a separate file with automatic naming?

---

First, a little history (in addition to what Alexey said):

In Mathematica versions earlier than 6, graphics were shown (displayed) as a side effect of `Show`.  `Show` was essentially the "print" command for graphics, much like how `Print` will display expressions as a side effect while returning `Null`.  Unlike `Print`, `Show` returned the `Graphics` expression in addition to displaying it.

`Graphics` expressions were formatted specially as `--Graphics--` in `OutputForm`, in order to prevent printing their guts in `InputForm` on screen every time some graphics were returned (similarly to how e.g. `InterpolatingFunction`s don't show their insides when formatted on screen).

Working with graphics looked like this:

[image]

The graphics were shown as a side effect and also returned.  The returned graphics was displayed as `--Graphics--` in output form.  (As Alexey said, you can restore the old behaviour by loading `` << Version5`Graphics` ``, but note that there are many graphics primitives that the old rendering method doesn't support, so many things will be broken.)

If you did not use the function `Show`, the graphics were not rendered on screen.

Most plotting function (such as `Plot`) automatically invoked `Show`.

It was possible to customize *how* precisely `Show` rendered graphics by using the [`DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DisplayFunction.html) `Graphics` option, which was by default set to `$DisplayFunction` which in turn was set to `Display[$Display, #1, "MPS"] &`, as Alexey notes.

In version 6 the big change was that now `Graphics` objects were formatted as a rendered picture when output into notebooks.  This meant that `Show` was not necessary any more.  `Graphics` were not rendered as a side effect any more.  Now instead of formatting them as the string `--Graphics--` they were formatted as the image they represented.  It also made sense to move the rendering (formerly done by an external PostScript renderer) into the Front End to allow for rotatable 3D graphics.

To prevent `Show` (and the plotting functions that invoked `Show`) from doing something as a side effect, `$DisplayFunction` was set to `Identity` in version 6.

The `Show` function lost its significance as a printing function for graphics, and it's now solely used for it's formerly secondary function: combining graphics.  (This explains why it's called `Show` when it doesn't actually show anything any more!)

---

So how does knowing this help you?  First, it makes it clear why `$Display` doesn't do anything any more.  It was used in the old default setting of `$DisplayFunction`.   Second, it gives a convenient way to answer the quoted question above.  You could define your own displaying function, possibly based on `Export`, and set the value of `$DisplayFunction` to it.

Be prepared for weird behaviour though.  `Show` is the function invoking the `$DisplayFunction` and `Show` is used differently today.  For example, in version 5 we needed to to `Show[a, b, DisplayFunction -> Identity]` to combine two `Graphics` objects without displaying them.  Today people will omit setting this option when all they want to do is combine graphics, so you might get extra invocations for `$DisplayFunction`.   Also, when implementing a custom plotting functions, people won't explicitly include `Show` to render the graphics, because this is not necessary.  So some newer plotting functions *might* not invoke the custom display function.

---

If you are writing a custom front end, you'll get the most reliable result if you do what the official front end does: render graphics only when the kernel returns a `Graphics` object to you.  Your front end would send this graphics object back to the kernel for rendering (using `Export` or `Rasterize`).  (And in turn the kernel will invoke the official front end in the background to do the actual rendering for it.)

---

Additional reading:

- [What does DisplayFunction->Identity do to graphics functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5682/12)

Comment: That's interesting. I think I would try to go for your last solution. But this means that I must reliably parse output in search for `Graphics[]`. It is not quite obvious to me how I can do this reliably as it seems to be returned as regular output. I have seen that there may also be `Graphics3D`. Do these always appear on separate lines at least? Otherwise I would need to search the closing bracket `]` which matches `Graphics[` or `Graphics3D[`. This would be hard because the square brackets could obviously appear in labels too. I.e. not all opening square brackets must have a closing match.

Comment: @highsciguy I'm venturing into increasingly unfamiliar territory here (for me), but instead of trying to figure out if you got Graphics or Graphics3D by parsing strings, you should figure it out by looking at *expressions*.  Retrieve an expression from the kernel, check what it is, then send it back for formatting: either as graphics, or as OutputForm/InputForm text.  Alternatively, use something like $PrePrint to process everything in the kernel and send some structured information to your front end, either containing graphics or text.

Comment: @highsciguy Actually my first idea (send to front end, figure out what it is, send back for formatting) is a very bad one.  The expression might be huge.  Instead, before it gets sent to your front end, the expression should be processed on the kernel side.  You can generate some structures expression specifically meant for consumption by your front end (i.e. not a simple string, but a Mathematica expression that contains the string an some annotation: is it a file name of graphics or is it a string to be printed?)

Comment: Actually it is worse. Part of the purpose of the custom front end is that it runs through a internet connection on a separate machine. Sending forth and back would indeed not make sense. However retrieving `Graphics` once might. This output could still be more compact than an exported graphics file. In principle the nicest solution would be if I could tell Mathematica to identify the packet as a `DISPLAYPKT` as it used to do with the compressed postscript output in old version. If the user is interested to see the graphics output he could translate these (if there is a local copy of Mathem).

Comment: @highsciguy I think that `Format` function is the way for you. You should define custom formatting functions for outputting different kinds of expressions to your custom front which cannot render graphics. Probably it is not needed to send complete `Graphics[...]` expression to your custom front end without specific requirement from the user.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ok, but in this case the parsing output problem remains. Or do you think that I can define a format which sends `DISPLAYPKT`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I could probably define a format which uses `DisplayPacket`. Did you mean this?

Comment: @highsciguy I did not mean this and do not recommend this way but you probably can do this. My point is that *by default* `Graphics[...]` should not be sent to your custom front end because it cannot render it. Instead you should instruct the kernel to send a stub like `-Graphics-` to your custom front end. And you should provide a way for a user to prompt actual `Graphics[...]` expression stored in the kernel.

Comment: I understand (I also understood now that `DisplayPacket` is merely an object type and not a function which I could use to generate them). Yes, indeed, if `Graphics` objects are not desired it will be better to suppress them. However my starting point was that I wanted to find a way to display them. If Mathematica is available on the user side too (for me it is), I can easily render Graphics objects using a second instance of Mathematica. However I need to identify them in the MathLink output stream.

Comment: Maybe the solution is to provide both, fully rendered display output (which may be used if there is no second instance of Mathematica) and `Graphics` output, depending on user wish. Based on your helpful comments, I tried to re-enable the old fashioned way of display output. However, I don't understand how to deal with the abbreviate postscript output. See my Edit 2 to the question.

Comment: @highsciguy You have not read carefully comments to my answer. I really think that relying on outdated graphical functionality is a bad idea. If you need to render modern *Mathematica* graphics, the only way is to rely on native FrontEnd, and I stress that *Mathematica* graphical expressions are NOT necessarily independent from the kernel because they may contain `Dynamic` constructs even if they do not contain any `Dynamic` literally. So storing `Graphics[...]` on remote computer would not generally allow you to render it without access to original kernel code which have generated it.

Comment: @highsciguy My point is that if you work with a kernel remotely you should minimize the traffic between the remote kernel and your custom front end. So everything should be stored in the remote kernel and only necessary information should be sent to the custom front end by request. You of course can instruct the remote kernel to use remote native FrontEnd to render graphics and sent it to your custom front end in any supported `Export` format (note that currently `Export` *always* works correctly only if a bitmap format is specified, export to PostScript does not always give correct result).

Comment: Yes, I understand your point and agree. I spent some time now experimenting with Export to svg. Though the produced plots mostly look nice I observed that they are indeed not always rendered correctly. So your information that only bitmaps are rendered correctly is useful again. I am still thinking about using a local official front end to render `Graphics` objects. Could it be possible to render the `Dynamic` elements you mentioned above static so that static `Graphics` are transferred? For exported raster picture they must have been rendered static as well.

Comment: I have made another edit exploring your proposal to use Format to redirect the output. See the question.

Comment: @highsciguy Your question about converting all `Dynamic` elements to static is interesting. It is not a trivial task AFAIK but probably possible. I can only say that it is generally impossible to do without the native FrontEnd. I think it is worth to create separate question about it.

Comment: @highsciguy About EDIT 3. I see that you got the main idea but there is a lot of work to polish it. First of all, you should clarify *when* graphics should be rendered to bitmaps and *how* these bitmaps are supposed to be passed to your custom front end? Your current approach imply that `Graphics` will be always rendered when it goes to the output channel. An alternative way would be to render it only on specific user request and *by default* send to custom front end only a stub like `"--Graphics--"` or `"--Graphics3D--"`. Which way is better depends on your goals.

Comment: @highsciguy The "*how*" part also depends on which raster formats will support your custom front end? Will it support *Mathematica*'s `Image` data structure? Instead of `Export` you could use `ExportString` and send the data directly from the kernel, but in this case you need a way to instruct custom front and about *what* is sent (one way is to send it with a `Head` like `DisplayPacket` - you can define your own `Head` of course).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Your reference to `ExportSring` is interesting again. However, currently I do not intend to embed the graphics in the front end. The solution will rather be to transfer the files separately. I am on Linux and there are several standard options to do this efficiently and automated. To reference the plots transparently in the front end I can simply display the file path (remote or local) and add functionality which opens the file in an appropriate viewer. My current focus is to implement a bullet proof way of generating the graphics. To transfer `Graphics` is still interesting tho.

Comment: @highsciguy If you do not intend to embed graphics in the front end, I think that good design decision would be to send to custom front end a stub like `"--Graphics--"` along with a link to a file. As to converting `Dynamic` to static standalone `Graphics`, I think you should create a separate question about this: this question cannot be answered in a comment and probably requires community support for finding a solution.

Comment: Here you go http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43585/render-dynamic-graphics-objects-static . The present question is essentially answered, I am not sure which answer to accept though.  Both were really useful.