# Render dynamic Graphics objects static

Tags: graphics, front-end, dynamic, kernel

As was discussed in the comments of another question ([MathLink Graphical Output (Plots) to File](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43148/mathlink-graphical-output-plots-to-file)), `Graphcis` objects produced by commands such as `Plot` could be used to plot graphics independent of the presence of a connection with the *Mathematica* kernel which generated it; i.e., it could be displayed in a separate instance of *Mathematica*. This would be useful to realize the display of plots in custom front ends connected to *Mathematica* with `MathLink`. The `Graphics` objects would in this case serve as exchange format between the kernel and the frond end.

However, as was pointed out to me, `Graphics` can contain dynamic content which is evaluated by the native front end by calling the kernel. Consider the example

```
SetOptions["stdout", FormatType -> InputForm];
myf1[min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ] := Table[count, {count, min, max}];
Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 5}, Ticks -> myf1]
```

which generates the output

> ```
> Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Line[{ ...}]}}}, 
>   {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True, 
>    AxesLabel -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {1., 0}, Method -> {}, 
>    PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0., 25.}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
>    PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, Ticks -> myf1}]
> ```

Note the final `Ticks -> myf1`. Is it possible make the kernel evaluate this output such that it is rendered static? In this case the `Graphics` should be made a static list of tics, however the solution would need to be generic enough to produce static output for all possible commands which generate graphics.

Comment: The command `FullGraphics` seems to be the right direction. But is it complete? And, if yes, how can I influence properties such as the aspect ration of the plot?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `FullGraphics` is extremely out-of-date: it seems that it has not changed much since version 5. Currently correct solution may be only FrontEnd-based. 
FrontEnd has a command `Convert Dynamic to Literal` under `Evaluation` menu which helps with `Dynamic` but not with `Ticks`.

A workaround for `Ticks` is `Export`ing the complete `Graphics[...]` as a Notebook, then `Import`ing it backward:

```
myf1[min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ] := Table[count, {count, min, max}];
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 5}, Ticks -> myf1];

Shallow[ImportString[ExportString[plot, "NB"], "NB"][[1, 1, 1, 1, -1]], 7]
```

> ```
> Ticks->FrontEndValueCache[$CellContext`myf1,{{{0.916667,FormBox[<<2>>]},{1.91667,FormBox[<<2>>]},{2.91667,FormBox[<<2>>]},{3.91667,FormBox[<<2>>]},{4.91667,FormBox[<<2>>]}},{{-0.520833,FormBox[<<2>>]},{0.479167,FormBox[<<2>>]},{1.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{2.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{3.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{4.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{5.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{6.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{7.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{8.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{9.47917,FormBox[<<2>>]},{10.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{11.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{12.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{13.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{14.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{15.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{16.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{17.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{18.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{19.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{20.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{21.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{22.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{23.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{24.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]},{25.4792,FormBox[<<2>>]}}}]
> ```

As you can see the `Import`ed expression contains explicit `Ticks` specification as a cache for the value of `` $CellContext`myf1 `` variable wrapped by `FrontEndValueCache`. To get standalone `Ticks` specification you should replace `FrontEndValueCache` with its second argument:

```
Shallow[ImportString[ExportString[plot, "NB"], "NB"][[1, 1, 1]] /. 
     FrontEndValueCache[var_, val_] :> val // ToExpression // InputForm, 7]
```

> ```
> Graphics[{{}, {}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Line[{<<77>>}]}}, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), 
> Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {1., 0}, PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0., 24.99999918367348}}, 
> PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, 
> Ticks -> {{{<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}}, {{<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, >     >     {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}, {<<2>>}}}]
> ```

Now you have got the complete standalone `Graphics` expression. Note that this workaround is for `Ticks` only and works only in the absence of `Dynamic` constructs. So before applying this you need to get rid of `Dynamic` using the `Convert Dynamic to Literal` command. This can be automatized:

```
myf1[min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ] := Table[count, {count, min, max}];
a = 8;
dynamicPlot = Dynamic[Plot[x^2, {x, 1, a}, Ticks -> myf1]];
nb = CreateDocument[dynamicPlot];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookDynamicToLiteral[
    FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]]]}];
Shallow[NotebookGet[nb], 8]
```

> ```
> Notebook[{Cell[
>    BoxData[GraphicsBox[{{}, {}, {<<2>>}}, 
>      AspectRatio -> NCache[<<2>>], Axes -> True, 
>      AxesOrigin -> {<<2>>}, PlotRange -> {<<2>>}, 
>      PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {<<2>>}, 
>      Ticks -> FrontEndValueCache[<<2>>]]], 
>    CellChangeTimes -> {3.60323*10^9}]}, WindowSize -> {701, 766}, 
>  WindowMargins -> {{480, Automatic}, {Automatic, 57}}, 
>  FrontEndVersion -> 
>   "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 6, 2011)", 
>  StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]
> ```

Note that in this case we able to kill two birds with one stone! We both have got rid of `Dynamic` and got complete `Ticks` specification without `Export`ing. What we need now is just to apply the replacement rule

```
FrontEndValueCache[var_, val_] :> val
```

and extract the `BoxData` expression from the `Notebook` expression, then convert box data into ordinary *Mathematica* graphics by applying `ToExpression`. Done!

P.S. In principle it is not necessary to convert `BoxData` to ordinary *Mathematica* graphics for transferring standalone `Graphics` to another computer. You can transfer the complete `Notebook` expression which can be stored in a textual file with `.nb` extension and opened by FrontEnd as ordinary Notebook. Even more, this way is more safe and gives much lesser possibility to corrupt anything.

---

### UPDATE

I just have found that the automatized way with the above method of calling `Convert Dynamic to Literal` command can lead to FrontEnd crash. More safe solution would be to get values of `Dynamic` variables directly from the kernel, so just stripping out `Dynamic` in the kernel. Here is the complete code which accounts only for simplest literal `Dynamic` and `Ticks` but not to other `Dynamic` constructs like `DynamicModule` etc.:

```
makeStandalone[expr_] := Module[{nb, nbExpr},
   nb = CreateDocument[dynamicPlot /. Dynamic[x___] :> x]; 
   FinishDynamic[]; Pause[.1];
   nbExpr = NotebookGet[nb] /. FrontEndValueCache[var_, val_] :> val; 
   NotebookClose[nb]; nbExpr];
```

I have added `FinishDynamic[]` and `Pause[.1]` because in some cases `Ticks` were not resolved even with `FinishDynamic[]`.

Comment: Do you have an example for the crash? Does it occur when the result is displayed, or when it is build?

Comment: @highsciguy In version 8.0.4 I get the crash every time with my original "automatized" code (under Windows 7 x64).

Comment: So far I did not see any crashes (I use Mathematica 9 on Linux). However I am not yet sure about the last part in your conversion. Everything seems to work if I use the native front end, but with MathLink I get `A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.`. Which is not too surprising, because the linked MathKernel will a priori not even know about an X-Window to display anything.

Comment: @highsciguy This message just states that FrontEnd is not connected to the kernel (the `$FrontEnd` variable is undefined).

Comment: Yes, I understand this. What I meant was that the FrontEnd on linux requires an X-Window (the piece of software in charge of displaying any graphical user interface). A X-Display is however not necessarily available if the login is on the command line (e.g. if I want to run Mathematica on a cluster). However I realized now that even `Export[Plot[..]]` requires a FrontEnd and thus a X-Display. It seems that the only way to circumvent it is to use a X-Display on a remote computer in general. This would however make it slow again.