# Bug in LogPlot reintroduced?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, logarithmic-scale

Running the first example

```
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}]
```

from the `LogPlot` documentation I get a plot without ticks highlighted in red

[image]

along with the error message

> Tick specification must be a list or a function

The issue is already documented in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111663/ticks-in-v10-a-bug-or-undocumented-change) and was attributed to a bug in `ticksfun`. However, the solution presented there does not work for me and the linked post claims that this bug was resolved in MMA 10.4. I'm using 11.2 (on macOS 10.13). Does that mean the issue was reintroduced in a different manner? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Do not put in the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: I'm using MMA 11.2 on Mac OS 10.13.2 and I get figure with tick marks on both axes.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry about that. If Cassini can't reproduce the issue, then perhaps it's just my installation. Is there some standard procedure, some steps to follow that can help identify the cause of this error on my particular system?

Comment: On the off chance that something got gummed up in your installation, please try [clean-starting *Mathematica*](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464).

Comment: Can't reproduce on `"11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"`

Comment: It works well (plot with ticks) in macOS 10.13.1 and MMA 11.2

Comment: Just got this same error as well (linux; mma 11.1). Interestingly it seems to be some kind of issue with the specific notebook: If I run the logplots in the examples everything displays fine. Unfortunately the notebook is too big to start afresh...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had this issue with 11.3.0 on Mac. For me it was easily fixed by enabling 'dynamic updating' in the Evaluation menu (had been disabled due to an earlier evaluation gone wild!)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43611/4999 -- Alexey Popkov's fix: ``ImportString[ExportString[LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}], "NB"], "NB"][[1, 1,
     1]] /. FrontEndValueCache[var_, val_] :> val // ToExpression``

Comment: Had to turn it of and on. Also, that would show up as impossibility to `Monitor[...]` stuff